# Background timer to update UI?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I got a little problem with my application.
I would like to update something on my UI every 10 seconds. I first used a `DispatcherTimer` for this but it will block my UI for a short time because the update method needs to load something from the web and this operation needs some time.
Now I thought about some kind of background worker and I found BackgroundTasks.
The problem with Background tasks is, as far as I understood it correctly, that they are supposed to serve as updaters even if the app is suspended. I don't need that.
I only would like to update if my app is running not if it is suspended.

Is there a good way to solve this?
Any suggestions what to use for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for starters, what have you tried? You can fire up a thread and dance with it. See: 1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx 2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178%28v=vs.80%29.aspx 3. https://www.google.ca/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=3&tok=BSvnKvGpLPeMsccfqVbvVQ&cp=9&gs_id=bz&xhr=t&q=thread+c%23&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=thread+c%23&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=d74e08ea70650bbd&bpcl=38897761&biw=1280&bih=892 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx 5. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.

Comment: I don't think that there is anything wrong with using a background worker for this. It shouldn't cause you any problems, but if you don't want to use one, you can use threading, which is basically what background worker does with some additions. Check my answer for information on how to do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need two things for it:

1. Timer

   You can update the UI in [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) with the 10 seconds interval.
2. Dispatcher

   You need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to change the UI without holding the *main UI thread*. Instead the method `Process` should be called on a *separate thread* (`Timer` method), other than *main UI thread*, and use `Dispatcher` in it to alert main UI thread for the change.

   ```
   Process() // method to be called after regular interval in Timer
   {
       // lengthy process, i.e. data fetching and processing etc.

       // here comes the UI update part
       Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate() { /* update UI */ });
   }
   ```

Comment: System.Timers.Timer cannot be used to update UI did you try it? this is what they wrote in MSDN but I have not tried it yet: If you use the System.Timers.Timer class with a user interface element, such as a form or control, without placing the timer on that user interface element, assign the form or control that contains the Timer to the SynchronizingObject property, so that the event is marshaled to the user interface thread.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried it and it worked you have to add the following line of code to assign the form as sync object   t.SynchronizingObject = (this);

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a thread that runs the part of your code that gets and processes the information from the website. This way, your form will not hesitate because it will be on a different thread than the processing part.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/172943/How-to-run-method-in-separate-thread) Article on code-project should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you could start a timer, which has a elapsed event, that occurs every time the timer passes a certain time cycle.

1. http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are missing proper cleanup: When the timer fires in the exact moment that the window was closed, I would get an uncaught TaskCanceledException when trying to run `Dispatcher.Invoke`. I didn't find help for this problem in other questions. I was able to solve it by unregistering the timer callback when closing the window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Timer clockTimer = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        clockTimer = new Timer(1.0); // 1 ms update to test for TaskCanceledException 
        clockTimer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        clockTimer.AutoReset = true;
        clockTimer.Start();
        Closed += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { clockTimer.Elapsed -= Timer_Elapsed; };
    }
    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate () {
            UpdateTime(now);
        });
    }
}
```

Obviously this is not a good idea if the window was re-shown. I tried adding a dtor, but it would never get called, probably due to cyclic dependencies.

Disclaimer: I don't know C#, so this might not be the best or proper way of doing things.