# Why can't I make BackgroundWorker() works as expected?

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I'm trying to run a the following code to test **BackgroundWorker**, but it makes me a lot of problems:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BackgroundWorkingTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        int counter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };

            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += BackgroundWorker1_DoWork;
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Start
        {
            counter = 0;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Cancel
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            progressLabel.Text = "0";
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) // DoWork
        {
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < 123456; i++)
            {
//              Application.DoEvents();    // This line doesn't help
//              Thread.Sleep(1);           // Enable this line solve the problem

                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i + 1);
                counter++;

                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) // Progress
        {
            progressLabel.Text = counter.ToString();
            progressLabel.Refresh();
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) // Completed
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
                MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Operation Completed");
        }
    }
}
```

**1.** For example, in the BackgroundWorker1_DoWork() method you can see the command:

```
Thread.Sleep(1);
```

If I disable it, then the "**Cancel**" button is not responding. I click it several times but it's not stopping the process and I'm not getting the "Operation Cancelled" message.

If I enable it then it works, but I don't want any Sleep(1) commands in my thread because it will just slow the process down and I don't want that.

If I enable the command:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

it's not helping at all, and the "Cancel" button also isn't responding during the counting.

**2.** Another problem that I see, is that if I'm using the command:

```
progressLabel.Refresh();
```

in the ProgressChanged() event, than something very strange happens. I can see on the panel that it finished the counting, and it shows on the label: "123456". But it takes almost one minute **after** that until it shows me the "Operation Completed" message.

If, after the label shows "123456", I set a breakPoint in the ProgressChanged() method, then I see that it keeps entering the method with e.ProgressPercentage parameter rising all the time.

How can it be? If I see on the panel "123456", doesn't it says that the process has finished? If it did, then why doesn't it shows me the "Operation Completed" message right away?

**3.** If I remove the "progressLabel.Refresh()" line, then I do get the "Operation Completed" message right away after the label shows "123456", but then it doesn't shows me the counting between 0 to 123456 (as I see when the Refresh() command is enabled).

**4.** Another thing that I don't really understand:

When I changed the code to use an array of several BackgroundWorkers instead of just one:

```
BackgroundWorker[] backgroundWorker1 = new ....
```

with the Sleep(1) enabled, I didn't get any error message, although that all the threads set text to the same label, and write values to the same counter.

Does it makes sense? How didn't I get any runtime error for updating the same label at the same time from several BackgroundWorker threads?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Probably related: [BackgroundWorker still freezes UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205015/backgroundworker-still-freezes-ui). Or this: [C# background worker frozen the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865629/c-sharp-background-worker-frozen-the-gui).

Comment: Thanks, I see that they suggest adding a Sleep() command in the DoWork method, but what's the point if it will slow my process by a lot? How can I report to the main UI about the progress of the process, without adding Sleep(1) command that will slow it down? In my program I need to have several BackgroundWorker threads, and I want to tell the UI about the progress of all of them but WITHOUT slowing them down.

Comment: Do not ever use `Application.DoEvents()`. It's evil incarnate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reporting progress too often:

```
for (i = 0; i < 123456; i++)
{
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i + 1);
```

...and the message loop of the window is overflowed by messages. So it can't serve the `CancelButton_Click` event in a timely manner.

Comment: So what should be the solution? How can I report to the main UI about the progress of the process, without adding Sleep(1) command that will slow it down?

Comment: @Xenon I guess the solution is to report progress less often. Don't report progress on every iteration, but on every 100, 1,000 or 10,000 iterations. Reporting progress a few times per second should be enough, don't overdo it.

Comment: And if I report less often, should I also add the Sleep(1) command? Or should it work without it?

Comment: @Xenon Adding sleep will be detrimental, the best choice here is to lower your frequency of reporting. You can either only report every X iterations or a percentage of the total iterations, or have a stopwatch and only report at the end of an iteration if that stopwatch is past a second or 5 seconds etc, and when reporting reset the stopwatch.

Comment: @Xenon whenever you can fix a problem with `Thread.Sleep(1)`, you have either a nasty problem or a bad fix. It's never an ideal solution. For me adding `Thread.Sleep(1)` anywhere is an admission of defeat.